# Python console logging and thousand separator while retaining structured logs compatibility

Tags: python

I am outputting large integer numbers, in their billions, to the console log. Currently, I am formatting the thousand separator syntax with f-strings for the sake to make them readable.

```py
logger.info("Items created %s", "{:,}".format(large_number))
```

Because this is clunky, is there a way to have the log formatted natively format integer numberes using a thousand separator (and default to the US locale, if have to)?

Edit: Note that `logger.info(f"Items created {large_number:,}")` is an incorrect answer. Because log indexing services like Sentry or Datadog would not be able to parse [structured logs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#implementing-structured-logging). It will also cause the string formatting operation executed unnecessarily on disabled log levels.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Thanks! I learned something new today. I'll read more about structured logging.

Comment: Structured logging becomes useful with monitoring services like Sentry or if you ever need to search your logs in larger devops projects. Otherwise you need to parse gigabytes of text files with regexes.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate logging now. I just thought it was just spitting out text but I guess being machine readable should still be considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered adding a filter to update large numbers?

```
import logging
import os

class Formatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        record.pid = os.getpid()
        return logging.Formatter.format(self, record)

def comma_filter(record):
    new_args = []
    for arg in record.args:
        if not isinstance(arg, int):
            new_args.append(arg)
        else:
            new_int = []
            str_num = str(arg)
            while str_num:
                new_int.insert(0, str_num[-3:])
                str_num = str_num[:-3]
            new_args.append(','.join(new_int))
    record.args = tuple(new_args)
    return record


main_logger = logging.getLogger()
main_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(Formatter('%(asctime)s %(pid)d %(name)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'))
handler.addFilter(comma_filter)
main_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

and in use:

```
>>> main_logger.info('testing: %s', 1234567)
2021-07-20 15:16:17,314 592732 root INFO: testing: 1,234,567
2021-07-20 15:16:17,314 592732 root INFO: testing: 1,234,567

>>> main_logger.info('%s thingies has %s widgets', 13, 7777)
2021-07-20 15:16:17,314 592732 root INFO: 13 thingies has 7,777 widgets
2021-07-20 15:16:17,314 592732 root INFO: 13 thingies has 7,777 widgets
```

If I understood the docs correctly, a filter attached to a handler will not be called unless the record is going to be logged (if the filter returns `None` the record is not logged).

Comment: Perfect. This looks like a solution to move forward. Let me explore further what else I can do with filters.

Comment: WOW!!  I never used these filters before, but I plan to explore their usage in future projects.  P.S.  I noted this function in my code review, but didn't grasp their capabilities from the docstrings.  You get my upvote on this answer.

Answer (score 2):

So my interpretation of your question(s) is that you want to know if the `logging` module within *Python* has a mechanism to natively format integers.

I have looked through the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8b93f0e696d3fc60fd311c13d5238da73a35e3b3/Lib/logging/__init__.py) of the `logging` module and can say that *there is no native mechanism to format integers*.  I'm still looking through the source code of Python to see if there is something you can use.

Additionally, the Python logging [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug) mentions the format requirements and limitations.

> `logging.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)`
>
> Logs a message with level `DEBUG` on the root logger. The msg is the message format string, and the args are the arguments which are merged into ***`msg` using the string formatting operator***. (Note that this means that you can use keywords in the format string, together with a single dictionary argument.)

---

Your secondary question involved the clunkiness of doing something like this:

```
logger.info("Items created %s", "{:,}".format(large_number))
```

or like this, which you stated is more readable, but presents a challenge when using `StructuredMessage.`

```
logger.info(f"Items created {large_number:,}")
```

I looked at the following Python Developer's Guide PEPs (Python Enhancement Proposals) for guidance.

- [PEP 378 -- Format Specifier for Thousands Separator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/#current-version-of-the-mini-language) defined the accepted methods for manipulating integers with thousands separators.
- [PEP 3101 -- Advanced String Formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) outlines the string formatting methods.

After reviewing these I don't see anything that will replace either `.format()` or f-strings.

---

Concerning the clunkiness. I don't know anything about the rest of your code, so I can only go off of the single line.  I'm wondering why you don't generate the logging message separately?

For example you could do something similar to this:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, handlers=[logging.StreamHandler()])

big = f'{123456789012345678901234567890:,}'
message = 'Items created:'
log_msg = f'{message} {big}'
logging.info(log_msg)
# output
INFO:root:Items created: 123,456,789,012,345,678,901,234,567,890
```

This type of structure can also be formatted to work with `StructuredMessage.`

```
import json
import logging

class StructuredMessage:
    def __init__(self, message, /, **kwargs):
        self.message = message
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s >>> %s' % (self.message, json.dumps(self.kwargs))

_ = StructuredMessage   # optional, to improve readability

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')

large_number = f'{123456789012345678901234567890:,}'
message = 'Items created:'

logging.info(_(message, foo='bar', bar='baz', num=large_number))

# output
Items created: >>> {"foo": "bar", "bar": "baz", "num": "123,456,789,012,345,678,901,234,567,890"}
```

The final part of your question was about using US locale.  If you follow the examples above you won't have to introduced another Python module into the mix.

---

After doing additional research of the Python source code I discovered the `format_field` function.  The code below uses this function and the module locale.

```
import json
import locale
import logging
from string import Formatter

fmt = Formatter()

# Set locale to the United States
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.ISO8859-1')


def format_large_integer(number):
    formatted_number = fmt.format_field(number, 'n')
    return formatted_number


class StructuredMessage:
    def __init__(self, message, /, **kwargs):
        self.message = message
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s >>> %s' % (self.message, json.dumps(self.kwargs))

_ = StructuredMessage   # optional, to improve readability

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')

large_number = 123456789012345678901234567890
message = 'Items created:'

logging.info(_(message, foo='bar', bar='baz', num=format_large_integer(large_number)))

# output 
Items created: >>> {"foo": "bar", "bar": "baz", "num": "123,456,789,012,345,678,901,234,567,890"}
```

Answer (score -3):

```py
logger.info(f"Items created {large_number:,}")
```